# finding the best matching of two arrays

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have two arrays, as such:

```
a1 = [x,y] 
b1 = [a,b,c]
```

I'm trying to find the "best matching" of them. Each item in one array can match to an item in the second array, and items can be unmatched. The arrays are sorted, and items can not match out of order. That is:

```
some valid orderings = [xa, yb, c], [a, x, yb, c], [a, x, b, c, y]  
some invalid orderings = [ya, xb, c], [b, x, a, c, y]
```

The "best matching" is defined by a cost function, which is c(a,b) for each pair or c(a) for each singleton.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say arrays have sizes n and m. Store a 2D array dp[ n ][ m ], where dp[ i ][ j ] is the solution of the same problem for first i elements of first array and j elements of second. Use the following equation to make dynamic programming work:

1. dp[ 0 ][ 0 ] = 0
2. dp[ i ][ j ] = max( dp[ i - 1 ][ j - 1 ] + c( a[ i ], b[ j ] ),        // make pair of a[ i ] and b[ j ]
                             dp[ i - 1 ][ j ] + c( a[ i ] ),                      // take a[ i ] as a singletone 
                             dp[ i ][ j - 1 ] + c( b[ j ] ),                      // take b[ j ] as a singletone
                              dp[ i - 1 ][ j - 1 ] + c( a[ i ] ) + c( b[ j ] ) // take both a[ i ] and b[ j ] as singletones
3. dp[ n-1 ][ m-1 ] is the answer

At step 2 if i = 0 use only dp[ i ][ j - 1 ] + c( b[ j ] ), and if j = 0 use dp[ i - 1 ][ j ] + c( a[ i ] ).